# Haproxy, rsyslog not working with udp

Tags: udp, haproxy, rsyslog

Recently I'm working with HAProxy, and this work perfectly.

Now I want to take log of HAProxy, and I stuck few days.

Working with ubuntu 14.04.
plz click under link for ss.

I change haproxy.conf

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1 local1
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 1000s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
```

and make rsyslog conf file on /etc/rsyslog.d/haproxy.conf

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 514
$template Haproxy,"%msg%n"
local1.* /var/log/haproxy.log
### keep logs in localhost ###
&~
```

and udp server is activatee

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OU4A.png

However, in /var/log rsyslog not logging even rsyslog is not make haproxy.log file!, when i make this haproxy.log file first, this is not working.

what can i do next? I also test logging with unix socket, this also not working.

plz help me.

Answer (score -1):

Probably your chroot configuration in global section is preventing writes to /var/log/haproxy.log

Newer versions of HAProxy and Ubuntu by default set up /dev/log as the destination for logging. This works even with a chroot